# build sqlite3 with electron is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to use SQlite database with electron app by following these steps:

1- npm install --save electron

2- npm install --save sqlite3

3- npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

4- //add rebuild and start script to package.json

```
"start": "electron .",

"rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
```

5- npm run rebuild

but it's show some errors:

```
    > sql3@1.0.0 rebuild C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3
> electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3

? Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  unpack_sqlite_dep
  'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171
,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_
modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed wit
h exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\
node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\wnw\\projs\\s
ql3\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.4.13" "--ar
ch=ia32" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "-
-module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\wnw\\projs\\sql3\\node_modu
les\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32" "--host=https://mapbox-nod
e-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v3.1.13/{toolset}/" "--packag
e_name=electron-v1.4-win32-ia32.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1

Error: Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel
build, please add the "/m" switch.
  unpack_sqlite_dep
  'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171
,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_
modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed wit
h exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\
node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\wnw\\projs\\s
ql3\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=1.4.13" "--ar
ch=ia32" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "-
-module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\wnw\\projs\\sql3\\node_modu
les\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v1.4-win32-ia32" "--host=https://mapbox-nod
e-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v3.1.13/{toolset}/" "--packag
e_name=electron-v1.4-win32-ia32.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\
src\index.js:277:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs\Su
bscriber.js:238:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs\Subscribe
r.js:197:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.j
s:128:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js
:102:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxj
s\Subscriber.js:128:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs
\Subscriber.js:102:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\s
rc\index.js:251:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs
\Subscriber.js:247:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber
.js:187:27)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 4294967295
npm ERR! sql3@1.0.0 rebuild: `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294967295
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sql3@1.0.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-12T11_04_58_33
3Z-debug.log
```

the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\wnw\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'rebuild' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prerebuild', 'rebuild', 'postrebuild' ]
5 info lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~prerebuild: sql3@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: sql3@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: PATH: C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\AppServ\php5;C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\WinAnt\bin;C:\Program Files\Git;C:\adb;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\AppServ\php5;C:\Program Files\WinAnt\bin;C:\Program Files\Git;C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: CWD: C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3
10 silly lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3' ]
11 silly lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: Returned: code: 4294967295  signal: null
12 info lifecycle sql3@1.0.0~rebuild: Failed to exec rebuild script
13 verbose stack Error: sql3@1.0.0 rebuild: `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`
13 verbose stack Exit status 4294967295
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wnw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid sql3@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\wnw\projs\sql3
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\wnw\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "rebuild"
18 verbose node v8.9.1
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 4294967295
22 error sql3@1.0.0 rebuild: `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`
22 error Exit status 4294967295
23 error Failed at the sql3@1.0.0 rebuild script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 4294967295, true ]
```

I followed all these steps:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: I think that `sqlite`-team doesn't prepare precompiled version for Node 8.x. You can try to install older Node or install Windows tools and build library independently. You can simple check errors by attempt to install sqlite `npm install sqlite`.

Comment: same thing with node 7.0.0

Answer (score 3):

Installing Python 2.7 didn't help so I installed [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)

and added a new script in the package.json `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"`

so after installing sqlite I install electron builder and type `npm run postinstall`

this solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to solve this issue as I could no longer build for Windows on my Mac after introducing sqlite3. I had to use a VM for this (I used Virtual Box). Below is a list of all the software I had to install on the VM in order to successfully build sqlite3.

- Microsoft Edge Windows 10 Virtual Machine
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/
- [or] Visual Studio 2017 Virtual Machine https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines
- Download Visual C++ Build tools
  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  When configuring the Visual C++ Build Tools, under Optional installs, choose **VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop** package
- Python 2.7 (choose add python.exe to PATH during install)
  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
- Node
  https://nodejs.org
- Git
  https://git-scm.com/download/win
- Yarn (optional)
  https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
- Visual Studio Code (optional)
  https://code.visualstudio.com

Now run your `rebuild` command and hopefully all is well.

**Please note, execution of all scripts must be run from the Developers Command Prompt for VS 2017 (Start Menu > Visual Studio 2017), which contains all the necessary environment paths to the VS build tools**

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue. 
Please install python 2.7 version and set the environment variable to C:\Python27 in windows and try again with electron rebuild.It will work this time.